# Reading along the diagonals of a 2D array in C

Tags: c

I currently have a character array with row and col size 15. My goal is to read along the diagonals (eventually in all four directions) and store the values in a separate array. The separate array has 15 columns and 30 rows, with excess values taken up by null characters.

Quick example for a 3x3 array:

Original Array:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

New Array:

```
A \0 \0
D  B \0
G  E  C 
H  F \0
I \0 \0
```

This is the code I've written:

```
// DiagUpRight Array
int initDiagUpRightArray(char wordArray[], char diagUpRightArray[]){
    // First, initialize array with null characters
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i=0; i<wDiagRowSize; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<wDiagColSize; j++) {
            diagUpRightArray[i][j] = '\0';
        }
    }

    // Next, array ought to put each diagonal (from bottom-to-top, left-to-right) in a row
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    for (i=0; i<wDiagRowSize; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<wDiagColSize; j++) {
            if (counter % 2) {
                 //counter is an odd number
                 diagUpRightArray[i][j] = wordArray[i][j]; //placeholder 
                 counter++;
            } else {
                //counter is an even number
                diagUpRightArray[i][j] = wordArray[i][j]; //placeholder
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

(I know this code is not very efficient; I am still a relative newbie to C and programming at all.)

wDiagRowSize and wDiagColSize are previously defined to be 30 and 15 respectively.

I know my problems are with the two lines with //placeholder comment, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Typo after `0` in `for (j=0); j<wDiagColSize; j++)`, remove the bracket.

Comment: Thank you! I'll fix that right now. Do you have any advice for the //placeholder lines?

Comment: Can you post the new array (`diagUpRightArray`) good values and the values you actually are getting? Just to see differences and know what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> I know my problems are with the two lines with //placeholder comment,
>   but I'm not sure how to proceed.

The `counter` and the distinction of cases odd/even is futile. In any case:

```
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0; i<wDiagRowSize; i++)
    for (j=0; j<wDiagColSize; j++)
    diagUpRightArray[i][j] =
      i<wDiagColSize  &&                   j<=i              ? wordArray[i-j][j]
    : wDiagColSize<=i && (k=wDiagColSize-1-j)>i-wDiagColSize ? wordArray[k][i-k]
    : '\0';
```